# Is /home a good place to put my (huge) MongoDB data file?

Tags: mongodb

(I'm not too familiar with admin stuff.)

My server has two disks/partitions, one mounted on `/`, the other much bigger one mounted on `/home`.

My MongoDB data file was at `/var/lib/mongodb` by default (I'm on a Debian).

I'm assuming I can just move data files around and set the conf in `mongodb.conf`.

Is having my data files on `/home` considered a good practice on "traditional" Linux file organizations?

If not, should I make a new partition of my large disk, and where should I mount it in that case?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is a personal development database then it seems `/home/<user>/var/lib/` would be one of the more unixish places to put it (but then the whole thing should be build with `/home/<user>` as root, i.e the conf would be in `/home/<user>/etc/`. If you are building from source `/usr/local` or `/opt/` might be more appropriate. Many people mimic the filesystem hiearchy in their home directories.

If this is a server, than generally the default (a.k.a expected) place to put it makes sense. That way as time progresses and new people use the server things are where they expect them to be.

Ideally partitions should be sized to fit what is going on them, not the other way around.

See the [FHS (Filesystem Hierarchy Standard)](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html) for where things go in Unix and why.